# how to upload file to azure blob with original file name using Fine Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading a file named my-image.jpg into my blob container with the endpoint of https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container on Azure.

After than it calls signature endpoint for SaS token and generate PUT request to Azure blob. Here i observed that PUT request does not contain original file name instead of that some GUID replaced file name.

I  want my original file name to be there in the PUT request so that the file will be uploaded on blob with the original name.

Would then https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/89056c3d-7bb3-my-image.jpg be the bloburi I send to my API while requesting a SAAS?

How do i achieve this ?

When my request hits my backend API to get a SAS, the blobUri comes in as /server/upload/some-guid-value.txt. I'm using the following options when instantiating an uploader. What am I doing wrong?

```
const uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container',

        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 'http://localhost:4879/api/getsas',
            cors:{
                expected: true,
                sendCredentials: false
            },
        }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, File Uploader azure will use a UUID to name your object. In almost cases, **this is the safest behavior**.

If you change this value, you will run the risk of overwriting existing files with new ones in the event of a name collision.

If you must save the blob in azure using a different name, you could modify the `blobProperties.name` option appropriately.

A value of "**filename**" will save the object using the original filename.

For more detail, you could read about this [option](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options-azure).